# Dynamically change connection property on connection obtained from Java JNI connection pool

Tags: java, jdbc, properties, connection, pool

I'm using Java and retrieving my database connections from a JNI connection pool (Weblogic Server).

I want to set the connection property, oracle.jdbc.V8Compatible="true", for the connections I retrieve because if this is not set then an Oracle bug is present that causes the wrong behavior when working with Dates and Timestamps.

There is a lot of already existing code where the previous coders worked around the Oracle bug using what I would consider to be a hack and bad practices.

So anyways, ideally, I would like to set oracle.jdbc.V8Compatible="true" for the newer code I am writing, but allow it to remain false for backwards compatibility for the already existing legacy code.  I'm afraid setting it to "true" across the board might break some of the older code.  It appears that since I'm retrieving my connections from a connection pool that there may not be an easy way to do this, aside from duplicating all my database connections in the pool so that they each have different properties, which I'm reluctant to do since there are multiple databases in play.

I just wanted to confirm that there isn't some way to modify the connection properties dynamically either during the retrieval of the connection from the pool, or after retrieving the connection from the pool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your choices are, in order of preference:

1. Refactor the existing code everywhere to handle the Timestamp object properly
2. Use separate connection pools for your code
3. Write conversion code from Timestamp to Date to maintain legacy code.
4. Continue using the workarounds others have started.

Answer (score 0):

See if your connection pool can expose it through JNDI. Then you can use i.e Jconsole to change it.